# How to allow POST method with Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I'm doing a web Flask app with "sign up" and "log in" functions. I'd like to use a POST method for the "sign up" function, like this:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Index"

@app.route("/signup/<username>,<password>" , methods = ['POST'])
def signup(username, password):

    return "Hello %s ! Your pw is %s" % (username,password)


if __name__== "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

But when I ran it, I received this error : "Method not allowed. The method is not allowed for the requested URL."

How can I do? Thanks in advance.

Comment: How did you access the URL? If you just go there in your browser that's a GET. Using curl you'd need `curl -X POST`.

Comment: I just go into the browser and test my application. How can I do with curl if I use PyCharm?

Comment: Using curl will not solve anything. Check out this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_wtf.htm

Comment: Thanks for your advice, but now I'm not interested to use an HTML form. Is this the only way to do what I want?

Comment: Nothing in the code you've provided would allow you to make a POST request from your browser.

Comment: Also, don't include passwords in URLs.

Comment: ok @dirn, so how can I make a POST request from my browser?

Comment: You need an HTML form. Or JavaScript.

Comment: ok, I got it. Thanks

Comment: I've just found an app called Postman that allows me to make a POST request.

Comment: @Frank Postman is for testing, it is not something you can make users use. Ultimately you will need to follow our advice and write a form or some Javascript making an AJAX request. Most websites you see are using forms for this, the rest are using AJAX. Please trust us on this.

Comment: @AlexHall I trust you, I will write a form but now, I have only to test my application. I'm sorry if I explain bad my need.

Comment: It is not hard to make your python take in form parameters instead of values from the URL, and postman will also allow you to emulate a form for testing.

Comment: Ok, I try to write an HTML form. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 14):

You could use something like this perhaps.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template, url_for, redirect

...

@app.route("/signup/<username>,<password>", methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def signup(username, password):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # Enter your function POST behavior here
        return redirect(url_for('mainmenu'))    # I'm just making this up
    else:
        return "Hello %s ! Your pw is %s" % (username,password)
        # Or you could try using render_template, which is really handy
        # return render_template('signupcomplete.html')
```

You'd have to flesh it out with the various things you need it to do, but that basic structure should be what you need.  I've used it myself in some projects.

Comment: thanks @coralv. I think I don't understand how I can do a POST request. My aim is to get username and password from the URL and then save them in a database.

Comment: Perhaps this could help you.  I used this course (it's free), and it went over a lot of good stuff about Flask and everything.  https://www.udacity.com/course/full-stack-foundations--ud088